# Send feedback button disappear when reporting ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising, popup

When I try to report an ad in Stack Overflow, this popup comes up to report it.

[image: report ad]

But after I attach an image and select Other, the Send Feedback button disappears from the screen.

[image: report ad with image]

The main issue is, I can't even scroll down to click the Send Feedback button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for notifying us! We were able to reproduce the issue and will fix this. I will update this post with any updates.

**Update May 17th**

This problem is fixed, feel free to comment below if you're still experiencing any issues.